# Can I adjust leading for 2 lines of text I highlighted?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, typesetting, typefaces, formatting

I am trying to adjust the leading of text. There are all different type sizes in the same text frame. I highlighted the two lines that I wanted to adjust the leading of but nothing changed. It seems all the text is inter-related I guess I am not using leading in the right way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether your lines end with a soft return, or a proper return (end of paragraph).

Then check any space before or space after settings.

And the vertical justification of the text box.

All these can alter the way leading works.

Comment: Aha yes! I used a soft return thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should work. But in the screenshot you shared you did not select the whole second line. If you decrease the line-height of a line but not select the break character it does not have any effect as it always takes the highest line-height for every line.